# What is this SOT-89 component marked 43B H42?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, markings

Can anyone help me identify the SOT-89 component in the picture below? It is marked \$\text{43B H42}\$. I have searched to find anything resembling a match, and I found that it could be both a programmable shunt regulator and a NPN power transistor.

[image]

Here following a sketch of the circuit surrounding the component of interest.

[image]

Comment: Might be a transistor, or a voltage regulator. Probably only answerable in the context of a schematic.

Comment: As you suggested, I've added a sketch of the circuitry surrounding the component I'm asking for.

Comment: Could it be a TL431?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's LM431SB. Check the datasheet and you can find its package marking.